# Why must an implementing property in VB.NET have matching 'ReadOnly' specifiers?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, interface, properties

The following works in C#:

```
interface I
{
    int X { get; }
}

class C : I
{
    public int X
    {
        get { ... }
        set { ... }
    }
}
```

The following does not work in VB.NET:

```
Interface I
    ReadOnly Property X As Integer
End Interface

Class C
    Implements I

    Public Property X As Integer Implements I.X
        Get
            ...
        End Get
        Set(value As Integer)
            ...
        End Set
    End Property
End Class
```

The error message `Implementing property must have matching 'ReadOnly' or 'WriteOnly' specifiers` is pretty self-explanatory, so I do know what's wrong here. It's also not a big issue, because it's quite easy to work around this limitiation.

I'm curious, though: Does anyone know why the VB designers decided to treat this case differently than in C#?

Comment: I don't see a readonly on your property in the C version of the interface?

Comment: @Nikki9696: The lack of a setter in the C# version is the equivalent, basically.

Comment: @Nikki9696 That's implied. The difference is that it doesn't need to be. But, Heinzi, you explicitly specify it in the VB.NET interface version, so that's a pretty big difference.

Comment: possible duplicate of [If an interface defines a ReadOnly Property, how can an implementer provide the Setter to this property ?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6307335/if-an-interface-defines-a-readonly-property-how-can-an-implementer-provide-the-s)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure about the VB side, but with the explicit interface implementation of I.X in C# you'd also get a complaint about the added setter:

```
interface I
{
    int X { get; }
}

class C : I
{
    int I.X  // explicit implementation of I.X
    {
        get { return 1; }
        set { }
    }
}
```

You get a similar error in C#.  For the VB, may want to check out this SO thread: [If an interface defines a ReadOnly Property, how can an implementer provide the Setter to this property?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6307335/if-an-interface-defines-a-readonly-property-how-can-an-implementer-provide-the-s)

Comment: Unfortunately, though, I'm not a VB guy so I'm playing with the VB to see how to do the same thing as your first C# example...

Comment: Looks like someone else had this issue, see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6307335/if-an-interface-defines-a-readonly-property-how-can-an-implementer-provide-the-s

Answer (score 1):

You need to provide a read-only property to implement I.X; if you want YourClass.X to be a read-write property, then the read-only that implements I.X should be given another name (e.g.

```
    Public Property Xreadonly As Integer Implements I.X
```

I'm not quite sure why .Net requires the use of three types of properties (read-only, write-only, and read-write), rather than simply allowing an object which declares a read-only property and a write-only property to be used as though it has a read-write property, but it does.  Perhaps its because they wanted to ensure that an override of a getter will follow the same inheritance path as an override of a setter, but it would seem there are cases where regarding getters and setters as separate items would be more useful (in some cases, for example, it may be useful to have a property Get method return a type which is distinct from, but coercible to, the Set method type; or it may be useful to have multiple overloads of Set; neither is allowed in .net, though).

Answer (score 0):

You have `ReadOnly` on the Property in the `Interface I` but not in the inherited `Class C` so the Property signatures don't match, hence the error. I'm sure you can't add a `set` accessor to a `ReadOnly` Property too.

Comment: The question is why can't you use a non readonly property to implement an interface that only wants a getter.